# CSS - How to make a 2 by 3 grid of icons?

Tags: html, css

so basically I want to have my icons displayed as 2 x 3 (2 Rows, 3 Columns) at all times, and when resized I want it to be 3 by 2, and the smallest is 1 Column with 6 Rows of images.

I can't seem to figure out what to do with flexbox, here's what my CSS looks like:

```
.skill-icons {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto;

}

.skill-icons>img {
  padding: 50px;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;

}
```

skill-icons is the div that I put all my icons in.
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzphE.png)

[What I have currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIabw.png)

Comment: please post your html as well. I can imagine what you did there, but it would be better if you can provide a minimal example

Answer (score 0):

You have probably put all your images inside same container. Considering you need to create a 3 x 2 (3 columns, 2 rows) grid ,you need to have two `html` elements with `.skill-icons` class.

```css
.skill-icons {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto;

}

.skill-icons>img {
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 128px;
  flex:1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-icons">
  <img class="" src="" />
  <img class="" src="" />
  <img class="" src="" />
</div>
<div class="skill-icons">
  <img class="" src="" />
  <img class="" src="" />
  <img class="" src="" />
</div>
```